# Lebesgue Integrability of $x^p |\ln x|^q$ over different intervals

Tags: integration, limits, functions, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am finding these types of questions very hard to answer.

I understood the method to part (a) even though it was difficult. I then look at part (b) and then a very similar looking question has a completely different method.

Why must they be answered so differently? Why can’t the same approach as in (a) be used?

Every question seems to have a new random approach to answer it and so I’m struggling to understand a general strategy I should use to decide the integrability of a particular given function.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Parts (a), (b), and (c) contain different vertical asymptotes of the integrand, contributed by different types of terms, and thus, are going to need different approaches (although (c) I would expect would have to be contained in the intersection of the answers to (a) and (b)).

Parts (d) and (e) are about completely different functions, and so, it's not surprising that they should need different answers.